# Is there a way to make Seaborn or Vincent interactive?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn, vincent

I've been trying to find a way to make Seaborn and Vincent interactive so that I can, for example, zoom in/out in a specific area of the plot in real time. Is this possible to do? Alternatively, are there other recommended libraries (that are not cloud-based services) that work well for visualizing time series data?

Comment: `seaborn` already is interactive (it's matplotlib behind-the-scenes).  How are you using it?

Comment: You might want to take a look at bokeh which has an interactive bent and plays well with pandas

Comment: You can also use [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is for your own benefit, rather than something you need to show to others, you can use IPython notebooks and the `%matplotlib nbagg` backend, at least for Seaborn, e.g.:

```
%matplotlib nbagg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
y = x**(0.5)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

If you don't already have IPython etc. set up, you can quickly test this out by creating a new notebook at [try.jupyter.org](https://try.jupyter.org/), pasting the code into a cell, and hitting `Shift + Enter` to run. Since this is running on a free VM it will be slow, running the notebook locally will mean panning/zooming is much smoother.